# There is one error when I am trying to move TFS report to a new server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, tfs

I try to debug a problem related to tfs report,I don't know why and really need  help. 
Recently I export one report from the old tfs server and deploy to the new server, I also copy the store procedures which related to this report in the old server database to the new server database. 
But the report just doesn't work. The error is as following,  The report rdl file and store processors in new  tfs server are exactly same like the old server, just didn't work for the new one.

An error occurred during client rendering.

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
>   Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'.
>   (rsErrorExecutingCommand) Query (1, 16) Parser: The syntax for
>   '@TFS_Date' is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: I think your old server has a different Default Language value, check if the issue is related to a date format difference between servers. Also I'd run the dataset query from SSMS with a hardcoded dummy parameter.

Comment: If you changed the TFS database in any way other than described or instructed by Microsoft you put yourself in an unsupported state! Imediatly restore a backup of before you made the changes!

Comment: @Steve, 1). please share the .rdl file you're working with. 2). What is the version of the new TFS server? TFS2013 or TFS2015?

Comment: Hey,Thank you all you guys for the comments and willing to help. I figured out the bug is that in one of the store procedure that I use in the report and another bug is I use the wrong data source. After I fix these two, the report is working.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest you to check your reporting service log files from below path,

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting Services\LogFiles
```

Usually the error messages here in *log file* shows us a perfect *solution*.

In your case, try to check that user has access to `dataset1's database.` (server database) by going to SQL Server Security tabs.

Also, check your store procedure. If you have joined with some other database's table then user must have access of that database too.

**Note:** This type of error messages you can find there in log file. So read it to solve the issue.

Comment: Hey,BuddyThank you all you guys for the comments and willing to help. I figured out the bug is that in one of the store procedure that I use in the report and another bug is I use the wrong data source. After I fix these two, the report is working.

Comment: It means, this answer could help to others. How did you find out the issue?